# How to obtain all physical address information of a process by writing module code

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am a novice and  I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Comment: It seems you are asking for a task (we are not here to program for here), instead of asking for a problem. "get all physical address of a process, inside a kernel", is a much more targeted question. Maybe a "get physical address from virtual address" is your real problem.

Comment: Well I just want to know if there is a way to get all physical address information of a given process

Comment: Kernel must know such information, but physical address is volatile. On virtual space, `cat /proc/<process>maps` gives you a list`. To convert to physical address: just check the page maps of a process.